# How to target HTML element from a specific class of a BODY element

Tags: jquery, html, css, stylesheet, parent-child

Using Drupal, the theme has a background color assigned to the `<HTML>` element. I'm creating a separate `print` CSS for ONE particular page, and wish to remove the background color ONLY for this page when the user prints the page. The `<HTML>` element has no class, or id, but the `<BODY>` element does.

```
<HTML style="background-color:#666">
  <BODY class=specialPage>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to specify that I want the parent element of `<BODY>`? Or some way of targeting `<HTML>` based on the class of `<BODY>`?

EDIT:

```
|------------------------|
|         <HTML>         |
|      |----------|      |
|      |          |      |
|      |  <BODY>  |      |
|      |          |      |
|      |----------|      |
|                        |
|------------------------|
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery you can do the following:

```
$('body.specialPage').parent('html').css({'background-color': 'white'});
```

This will work whether another element contains `body` or not.

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JARAd/).

Also, you should use lowercase letters for your html elements, `html` instead of `HTML`.

Comment: No need to use the map syntax for `css()` sinice you're only changing one property.

Comment: I tend to use that syntax simply because I might add more properties later, and thus it tends to make my code base more maintainable. Just personal preference.

Comment: @Mechaflash if this is what you ended up doing, be sure to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("body.specialPage")
    .closest("html")
    .css("background-color","");
```

The first line targets the body element with the special class. Then we select its parent HTML tag and 'remove' its background color. The beauty is that it won't select the parent HTML if the class isn't specifically set to the one you're looking for.

This would also work:

```
if( $("body").hasClass("specialPage") ){
    $("html").css("background-color","");
}
```

jQuery's `hasClass()` returns a boolean (`true` if it has the class and `false` if it doesn't), so is the body tag has the class you're looking for, it will run the code in the if function, which again 'removes' the background color from the HTML tag.

Answer (score 3):

You could try overriding the background-color style from the HTML tag with the !important modifier..

```
<HTML style="background-color:#666">
  <BODY class=specialPage style="background-color:#123 !important">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is probably the preferred method since styling really shouldn't happen in JavaScript. +1

Comment: Created an edit in my question. This would work except for the rest of the default styling.